# Is a ClientId and Certificate always needed for a Microsoft SharePoint Provider hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, ssl

I do not understand the following thing in SharePoint Provider Hosted Add-In  development:

When you create a SharePoint Provider Hosted Add-In you create a ClientId/-Secret and also for High Trust Apps a SSL certificate on the IIS with a password.

My question is:

Do i need to create for each of my provider hosted applications a dedicated SSL certificate and provide it with the password to the developer? And also always need to create a separate ClientId and -secret for each app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SharePoint Online (low-trust apps) and on-premise in low-trust scenario:

- for every new addin you need new ClientId and ClientSecret
- no need for SSL certificates (since we are using low-trust and OAuth in order to obtain access token)

For SharePoint on-premise (2013, 2016, S2S authentication, high-trust):

- for every new addin you need new ClientId
- no need for ClientSecret, since you are using S2S authentiation based on certifcate
- you may use one SSL certificate for all your high-trust addins (this kind of certificate registered with `-IsTrustBroker` flag), or you can create separate certificate for every addin. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945118.aspx#Deciding)

Comment: [This](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/security-in-sharepoint-apps-part-1/) blog post goes into some detail about how Provider-hosted apps get the context from SharePoint.  Describes the role of the secret and the certificate in low and high trust apps.

Comment: I found on this website https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shariq/2013/05/07/how-to-set-up-high-trust-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-troubleshooting-tips/ that there is needed a dedicated url for the web host? Maybe i dont need this instead i need the HighTrustConfig-ForSingleApp.ps1 script from MSDN for using a shared cert?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite understand you. In case if your addin is a web application, then of course you need dedicated url. For shared certificate you need to use `HighTrustConfig-ForSharedCertificate.ps1` and `HighTrustConfig-ForSingleApp.ps1` for certificate per addin

Comment: @Kai: thanks. i will try the scripts within the next hours. You mean HighTrustConfig-ForSharedCertificate.ps1 **OR** HighTrustConfig-ForSingleApp.ps1 !?

Comment: It depends on your strategy. The link I sent you - [Deciding between using one certificate or many for high-trust SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945118.aspx#Deciding) describes pros and cons for each strategy.